# What is the difference between an Instrument and Equipment?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-systems, flight-instruments, equipment, caa-uk-regulations

In an aircraft, what things is an instrument and what things is an equipment? For example the ILS, is the Antennas located in the runway considered to be an instrument or an equipment? Or is there another example to differentiate both?

Comment: Not all equipment are instruments. The voice radios for instance are definitely equipment, but they are not instruments.

Comment: "Equipment" is a very broad term and it covers more or less anything physical, e.g. the "equipment list" for a light Cessna includes the paint. "Instruments" are things that display measured information to the pilot in some way: altimeter, airspeed indicator etc. But that's just my opinion; words change their meanings in different contexts, and I'm not sure what context you're asking about. But if you don't get a useful answer here, you might try [english.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: All instruments are equipment, but not all equipment are instruments.

Answer (score 2):

In the aircraft an instrument is related to equipment providing displayed data.

Comment: I disagree that long answers are better.  Sometimes a concise clarification is all that is needed.  A long winded overblown answer to very simple question is unnecessary, and can actually drive readers away.